# How to merge two colletion in MongoDB of same type using single Query

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections as  `A` and `B` and both having document as below :

> collection A

```
{_id:id1
 name: Mohan
 age:25
}
```

> collection B

```
{_id:id2
 name: sohan
 age:29
}
```

I want to merge this two collection `A` and `B` and expected output as below:

```
{_id:id1,
 name: Mohan,
 age:25},
{_id:id2,
 name: Sohan
 age:29
}
```

Any one knows how to merge this two collections? And I don't want to be create a new collection.

Comment: Are yuo performing a JOIN or are you actually merging two collections?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all documents of collection1 to collection2 then you need to use foreach function as given below :

```
db.collection1.find().forEach(function(doc){db.collection2.save(doc)});
```

The collection2 will contains all document from collection1 as well as all of its own documents.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I want to query the result not to save in collection2. Is any other option?